# Using FormData to post/patch to a django ArrayField

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

Because I'm posting a file I'm having to use $http, and a FormData object.  When I post an instance with an array that I stringified, the validation says I'm not posting an integer.

My model looks like this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    work_week = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), default=[0,1,2,3,4], size=7)
```

My serializer looks like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    work_week = serializers.ListField(
       child=serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=6)
    )
```

The javascript post looks like this

```
let data = {
    work_week = [1,2,3];
}

let fd = new FormData();
for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(data)) {
   if (key === 'work_week') {
      val = JSON.stringify(val);
   }

   fd.append(key, val)
}

$http({
    url: full_url,
    method: this.method,
    data: fd,
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
  })
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
{work_week: ["A valid integer is required."]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are stringify-ing work_week... this turns that value into a string "[1,2,3]" instead of leaving it as a proper array. However, the REST framework doesn't handle conversion from strings to lists in the serializers. The simplest approach is probably to provide your own `to_internal_values()` in the serializer:

```
def to_internal_values(self, data):
    if isinstance(data['work_week'], str):
        data['work_week'] = json.loads(data['work_week'])
    do_any_validation_here()
    return data
```

Of course, this is for a serializer with just the list field... you'll need to adapt it to handle the remaining fields. You might be able to do something similar for the single field without impacting the rest of the serializer by overriding validation for this field:

```
def validate_work_week(self, value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        value = json.loads(value)
    do_any_validation_here(value)
    return value
```

... but I don't recall if this happens soon enough in the process to prevent the serializer from rejecting the string.